# Set of functions from nonempty set to reals, vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a nonempty set, and denote by $\textbf{R}^X$ the set of all functions $f: X \to \textbf{R}$. How do I verify that $\textbf{R}^X$ is a vector space under the operations$$(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x),\text{ and }(r \cdot f)(x) = r \cdot f(x)?$$I am quite stuck and some help would be nice...

Comment: There are several axioms for vector spaces and you need to check them.

Comment: By definition; by definition.

Comment: Prove that each of the [axioms of a vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) apply.